# Подмена элемента на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу реализовать следующее:

- Есть `label.calendar-button`, при нажатии хочу получить в его же `div` `input` с возможностью указания даты (возможно с `timepicker`).
- После выбора даты необходимо вернуть `.calendar-button` с заданным значением даты. Возможно?

Сейчас имею:

```
<label class="calendar-button">
  <div id="content">
    <input type="radio" name="date" id="16092017">Выбрать день<br>
    <span>не выбрано</span>
  </div>
</label>
```

После нажатия нужно получить:

```
<label class="calendar-button">
  <div id="content">
    <input type="text" name="date" value="" placeholder="Укажите дату">
  </div>
</label>
```

И, соответственно, после указания даты получить обратно:

```
<label class="calendar-button">
  <div id="content">
    <input type="radio" name="date" id="*Выбранная дата*">Выбор даты<br>
    <span>*Выбранная дата*</span>
  </div>
</label>
```

Интересует конкретно javascript, как и что нужно навешать?

Comment: JS != java, ну сколько можно уже

Comment: Прошу простить, новичок, не шарю. у Вас есть какие-то предложения по JS?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо сделать следующие шаги.

- При нажатии на кнопку "Выбрать день" скрывать элементы для показа, показать элементы для ввода.
- При нажатии на кнопку "Ок" скрыть элементы для ввода, показать элементы для показа, записать значение в span.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/4kt3ctou/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-show-input').on('click', function() { //Устанавливаем обработчик нажатия на кнопку
    $('#content-show').hide(); //прячем контет для показа
    $('#content-input').show(); //показываем контет для ввода
  });
  $('#btn-hide-input').on('click', function() { //Устанавливаем обработчик нажатия на ОК
    $('#content-show').show(); //показываем контет для показа
    $('#content-input').hide(); //прячем контет для ввода
    var dateVal = $('#input-date').val();
    $('#result').text(dateVal); //Записываем в span значение, введенное в инпут
    $('#date-input-show').val(dateVal); //Записываем в input значение, введенное в инпут
  });
});
```

```css
#content-input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="calendar-button">
  <div id="content">
    <form id="content-show">
      <input type="button" id="btn-show-input" value="Выбрать день">
      <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date-input-show">
      <br>
      <span id="result">не выбрано</span>
    </form>
    <div id="content-input">
      <input type="text" name="date" value="" id="input-date" placeholder="Укажите дату">
       <input type="button" value="ok" id="btn-hide-input">
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Спасибо, практически то, что нужно! но есть еще загвоздка: <input type="radio" name="date" id="*Выбранная дата*">. По факту мне нужно записать значение и отправить его же формой в обработчик

Comment: @ЮрийБондаренко Вы хотите значение выбранной даты записать в атрибут ** id**  инпута с типом `type="radio"`? Это очень странно. Думаю, вам надо сделать скрытый инпут. Я обновлю свой ответ.